# Как добавить дополнительные текстовые поля с сохранением их отображения?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как лучше применить ввод текста в несколько новых текстовых полей?

Если других вариантов нет, то как создать текстовые поля таким образом, чтобы они сохранялись после закрытия формы? И если текстовые поля можно создать, то как новым полям задать команды, например генерацию `GUID` или удаление значений при нажатии `DELETE`.

Код, который минимально отображает возможности, для одного текстового поля:

```
public partial class FormSetting : Form
{
    int cLeft = 1;
    public FormSetting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewTextBox();
    }
    public TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt.Left = 25;
        txt.Text = "TextBox " + cLeft.ToString();
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;
        return txt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам код для добавления и удаления текста в автоматически добавляемые текстбокси.

```
int cLeft = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
           AddNewTextBox(i);
        }
    }
    public void AddNewTextBox(int number)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt.Left = 25;
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;
        txt.Width = 200;
        txt.Height = 10;
        txt.Name = string.Format("myTextBox{0}",number);
    }
    private  void ResetTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            ResetTextBoxes(c.Controls);
        }
    }
    private void AddText(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Text = string.Format("Text for {0}", tb.Name);
            }
            ResetTextBoxes(c.Controls);
        }
    }
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddText(this.Controls);
    }
    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetTextBoxes(this.Controls);
    }
```

Не знаю проблема решена или нет,я то забил ;) написать ответ добавляю сейчас

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    private int cLeft = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddControls(); 
    }
    public void AddControls()
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt.Left = 25;
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        Controls.Add(txt1);
        txt1.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt1.Left = 150;
        Button b1 = new Button();
        Controls.Add(b1);
        b1.Top = cLeft * 25;
        b1.Left = txt1.Left*2;
        cLeft++;
        b1.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            b1.Enabled = false;
            AddNewTextBox();
        };
    }
 }
```

Comment: Не совсем, то. Имелось ввиду добавление строк. Допустим есть два текстовых поля и две кнопки, вот их и нужно дублировать каждый раз, когда заканчивается место. Если я введу первые значения, то мне будет некуда вносить следующие значения, поэтому и нужны дополнительные поля...

Comment: то есть если уже текстбокси заполнени тогда надо в форме дублировать те же текстбокси и кнопки да?

Comment: Да, только пустые, чтобы тем же способом при нажатии на кнопки выполнялись команды. Каждая строчка это отдельные два текстовых поля и две отдельные кнопки для них.